# How to set map padding in Here Maps Android SDK

Tags: android, here-api

Google Maps Android SDK has a setpadding option to adjust map view location and behavior. Here's the description of this API: [Google Map setpadding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding)

Is there an API equivalent in Here Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest would be:
[Map#setClipRect](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapfragment.html#topic-apiref__setcliprect-viewrect-pointf)

It will allow you to have a re-positioned transform center and clip the rendering to the specified area.

Another thing you can do is change the transform center of the Map to be the center of the area you want focus on. Also, attach a MotionEvent handler to consume all events outside of the desired area.